# XML not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When I am trying to build my app using xamarin for android, an error pops up saying

> Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in line 17

I cannot seem to find where the bad structure is though. As it seem, it has something to do with the way I try to include buttons in the grid layout. I am sure it is something stupid but I just cannot find it. I included my code below:

New error:

> Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in line 17

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:paddingLeft="40"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="20"
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:height="100"
        android:width="100" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: You didn't complete the opening `GridLayout` tag with a `>` before trying to start putting child `Button`s in it...

Comment: @underscore_d When I do that the error changes to >Error Parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: So [edit] your post with the latest XML and the verbatim quote of the latest error, including line number implicated.

Comment: @underscore_d I made the change...

Comment: The wrong one. The `>` should be at the end of the line `android:rowCount="20"`, before the line `<Button`. You should not end the `GridLayout` tag before you have set its attributes... Perhaps don't code XML by hand until you know its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you count the line 17 that it points out to, you reach this line

```
android:height="100"
```

Notice the "unbound prefix" or how there is no unit (dp/sp) against that value.
Please fix that and all the other length measurements to contain a unit of measurement, so that the prefix is bound:

```
android:height="100dp"
```